# WSO2 AppServer v5.0.0 unable to find InitialContext class?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to run a very simple app to the new WSO2 AppServer (version 5.0.0) but there seems to be something very odd going on. When I try to access a page that does a simple JNDI lookup, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP     Generated servlet error: 
Only a type can be imported. javax.naming.InitialContext resolves to a package 
An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /jndi.jsp 
Generated servlet error: InitialContext cannot be resolved to a type 
An error occurred at line: 11 in the jsp file: /jndi.jsp Generated servlet error:
InitialContext cannot be resolved to a type
```

The page contains just the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext" %>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>JNDI Test</title>
  </head>
 <body>
    <h1>JNDI Test</h1>
 <%
   InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
 %>     
 <p>Context: <%= ctx.getNameInNamespace() %>

   </body>
</html>
```

It seems that the tomcat compiler is unable to "see" the java runtime classes, but I can't figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jndi look up code to a seperate java class and invoke it from your jsp page.

Comment: While I _can_ do this, I really would not like to without a good reason. AFAIK the above code is JEE compliant, so AS should be able to run it unchanged.